# Триггер на вставку новой записи, отрабатывающий при вставке записи в одной таблице

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Доброе время суток форумчане.

Есть таблица «Words» с полями:

```
«id» «field2»  
  1   двор  
  2   улица
```

Я создал перекрестную таблицу «Synonym», в ней заполняются 4 поля («id» «field2» «words_id» «synonym_id»).
Есть «Synonym»

```
«id» «field2» «words_id» «synonym_id»
 1     двор       1          2
 2     улица      2          1
```

Я хотел написать в «Synonym» триггер на вставку «alter insert».
Чтоб при вставки в «Synonym» первой строки (с ссылкой), автоматически в «Synonym» вставлялась вторая строка (см. выше).
Я попытался написать *первый* вариант (не конечный) триггера.
Тогда триггер должен содержать, что-то типа:

```
insert into SYNONYM (field2, words_id, synonym_id)
 select s.field2, s.words_id, s.synonym_id from SYNONYM s join inserted i on (s.ID = i.ID);
```

в данном триггере, нужно еще обращаться к таблице «Words».
но в IBExpert, вылетает ошибка, что псевдотаблицу «inserted» не знакома.
В MySQL такое возможно, а в обычном?
Или как-то можно по-другому решить эту проблему?

Заранее **спасибо**
P.S.
Сразу может вставляться несколько новых записей, на все, нужно подобавлять конвертированную стоку

Comment: Псевдотаблицы inserted/deleted - это из T-SQL.
Попробуйте стандартные new/old.

Comment: ну что я и предпологал появились бессконечные циклы вставки, т.е. я вставляю запись и понеслись втавки триггером "*Too many concurrent executions of the same request.*"